# Can I merge my branch with the master while there is an open pull request on that branch?

Tags: git, github

I forked one repository (let's call it 'X') to use on my research as a starting point. I have discovered some bugs in X and created a new branch on my fork to fix them. After fixing those bugs, I created a pull request to X and the request is pending.

Can I merge that branch with my master, while the pull request is still pending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I merge that branch with my master, while the pull request is still pending?

Absolutely. The fork belongs completely to you! You can do anything you like with it. And what you do will not affect what happens to the pull request that's pending at the upstream (X).